# Connecting SQL Server to Azure Database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure, entity-framework

I have been developing applications using ASP.NET MVC but using the IIS localhost for testing. I want to deploy for production now but a bit stuck.

I have subscribed for the Azure free subscription. I have been able to deploy the application to azure and it is live on "mydomain".azurewebsites.net. The issue I am having now is the database.

I want to connect a database to it. I used EF Code-First approach throughout the project. My questions are below:

1. What will be the content of my `Web.config` as regards connection string before deploying the application.
2. How do I create a database and connect it successfully to my application on Azure

Comment: does this answer your question? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations

Comment: @Nonik, No sir. Can you kindly guide if i have to edit the web.config file in development before deploying and also i have created the database in Azure, how do i connect it to the application as it is Codefirst

Comment: web.config is intended to be site specific, i.e. every instance of web.config could be unique. So you should never be deploying it.

Comment: @DaleK, Where do i put the connection string generated on  Azure?

Comment: web.config I assume? Is that were you use it locally?

Comment: yes. This is what my web.config looks like in local.   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=PRECIOUSMUM;Initial Catalog=CreditFacility_Web;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="CreditFacilityContext" connectionString="Data Source=PRECIOUSMUM;Initial Catalog=CreditFacility_Web;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read this article, then you will know what code-first does at runtime.

[Database Initialization in Entity Framework 6](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx)

[image]

[image]